# How to Marker Manager with value in Array

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have been searched in google how can i use Marker Manager with value in Array i have a lot of Marker with Longitude and latitude information in Array see an example code as bellow

```
var locations = [  
                            ['rabat', 33.906896,-6.263123],
                            ['rabat2', 34.053993,-6.792237],
                            ['agdal', 33.994469,-6.848702],
                            ['casa', 33.587596,-7.657156],  
                            ['casa2', 33.531808,-7.674601],  
                            ['casa3', 33.58824,-7.673278],  
                            ['casa4', 33.542325,-7.578557],  
                            ['agadir', 30.433948,-9.600005],  
                            ['kech', 31.634676,-8.000164],  
                            ['oujda,', 34.689969,-1.912365],
                            ['tanger,', 35.771586,-5.801868],
                            ['JIJEL-ACHOUAT',36.8,5.883333333,1],
                            ['JIJEL-PORT',36.81666667,5.883333333,2],
                            ['SKIKDA',36.88333333,6.9,3],
                            ['ANNABA',36.83333333,7.816666667,4],
                            ['EL-KALA',36.9,8.45,8],
                            ['ALGER-PORT',36.76666667,3.1,9],
                            ['DELLYS',36.91666667,3.95,10.4],
                            ['DAR-EL-BEIDA',36.68333333,3.216666667,12.08571429],
                            ['TIZI-OUZOU',36.7,4.05,13.77142857]
                        ];
```

what i need is when i have the page i need just showing some markers and when i zoom my maps i want to get the other marker i tried something but it didn't works see the code as bellow :

```
                var mgr;
                var map;
            function initialize(){

                  var mapOptions = {
                                   zoom: 4,
                                   center: new google.maps.LatLng(28.975750, 10.669184),
                                   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
                               };
                        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('resultcnn'), mapOptions);
                        mgr = new MarkerManager(map);

                   var locations = [  
                            ['rabat', 33.906896,-6.263123],
                            ['rabat2', 34.053993,-6.792237],
                            ['agdal', 33.994469,-6.848702],
                            ['casa', 33.587596,-7.657156],  
                            ['casa2', 33.531808,-7.674601],  
                            ['casa3', 33.58824,-7.673278],  
                            ['casa4', 33.542325,-7.578557],  
                            ['agadir', 30.433948,-9.600005],  
                            ['kech', 31.634676,-8.000164],  
                            ['oujda,', 34.689969,-1.912365],
                            ['tanger,', 35.771586,-5.801868],
                            ['JIJEL-ACHOUAT',36.8,5.883333333,1],
                            ['JIJEL-PORT',36.81666667,5.883333333,2],
                            ['SKIKDA',36.88333333,6.9,3],
                            ['ANNABA',36.83333333,7.816666667,4],
                            ['EL-KALA',36.9,8.45,8],
                            ['ALGER-PORT',36.76666667,3.1,9],
                            ['DELLYS',36.91666667,3.95,10.4],
                            ['DAR-EL-BEIDA',36.68333333,3.216666667,12.08571429],
                            ['TIZI-OUZOU',36.7,4.05,13.77142857]
                        ];

                                   google.maps.event.addListener(mgr, 'loaded', function() {
                                   for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
                                       var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                           position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),

                                           map: map
                                       });
                                       mgr.addMarkers(marker,5);
                                   }
                                   mgr.refresh();
                                  }); 


            }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't add the markers to the map, let the MarkerManager do that
2. If you are only adding a single marker, use `.addMarker`, not `.addMarkers`

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/ee7nbaL1/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var mgr;
var map;

function initialize() {

  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(34.6479355684, -0.2292535),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('resultcnn'), mapOptions);

  mgr = new MarkerManager(map);

  var locations = [
    ['rabat', 33.906896, -6.263123],
    ['rabat2', 34.053993, -6.792237],
    ['agdal', 33.994469, -6.848702],
    ['casa', 33.587596, -7.657156],
    ['casa2', 33.531808, -7.674601],
    ['casa3', 33.58824, -7.673278],
    ['casa4', 33.542325, -7.578557],
    ['agadir', 30.433948, -9.600005],
    ['kech', 31.634676, -8.000164],
    ['oujda,', 34.689969, -1.912365],
    ['tanger,', 35.771586, -5.801868],
    ['JIJEL-ACHOUAT', 36.8, 5.883333333, 1],
    ['JIJEL-PORT', 36.81666667, 5.883333333, 2],
    ['SKIKDA', 36.88333333, 6.9, 3],
    ['ANNABA', 36.83333333, 7.816666667, 4],
    ['EL-KALA', 36.9, 8.45, 8],
    ['ALGER-PORT', 36.76666667, 3.1, 9],
    ['DELLYS', 36.91666667, 3.95, 10.4],
    ['DAR-EL-BEIDA', 36.68333333, 3.216666667, 12.08571429],
    ['TIZI-OUZOU', 36.7, 4.05, 13.77142857]
  ];

  google.maps.event.addListener(mgr, 'loaded', function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
      });
      mgr.addMarker(marker, 5);
    }
    mgr.refresh();
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#resultcnn {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markermanager/src/markermanager.js"></script>
<div id="resultcnn"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but what i need is when i am in zoom : 4 i need to display for example 5 markers and when i am in zoom :5 i need to display 10 items ..... because i have 1000 data

Comment: And where did it specify that in your question?  For that matter, where in your code did you attempt to do that?

Comment: yes the code that i shared  is the code that i tried to do it

Comment: All your markers have a minimum zoom of 5; which ones did you try to display differently?  How do you specify the ones that are different?

Comment: that what i search how can i specify some marker a zoom and another marker another zoom this and example how my solution look like
[link]http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markermanager/examples/weather_map.html[/link]